AC Motor Question Operating HALT Experiment
I'm using a TSA200-230-109 pump motor (part number 11035274) to operate a load and experiment with stressing a custom hydraulic system.

Above is the nameplate data, very limited.
I am a motor-moron and I am curious about this S3 rating. Right now, I am loading the motor at 400-450A continuous for about 12 seconds and shutting it off, see graph below

We are hitting about 70C ambient and I'm wondering what happens if I increase this duty cycle. I am also very unclear on the actual period, is it 10 minutes, 10 years? If I let it run for 30 minutes and shut it off for 70 minutes, am I gonna blow up in that 30 minutes? That feels like something I should be able to find in a datasheet, but I've been struggling to find a datasheet.
Mostly I'm curious what my limits are for current and operating time. If I run an S3 motor continuously below the effective current, am I going to cause mechanical damage to say the insulation of the motor? If I run it at 100A continuously, is that okay or will it run into problems with longevity?
I am happy to add any clarification needed and will continue my hunt for the dang datasheet, I wanted some input on S3 ratings and what this means for operating the motor.
